# How to display vpython input inline in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, vpython

I am trying to use vpython (version 7) to create a 3D model of a sphere in Jupyter notebook but I am not getting an output. What command should I add so that Jupyter displays the sphere inline?

Here is my code:

```
from vpython import *
display()
sphere()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please post your commands/code and error messages here? Otherwise it's hard to help you. Thanks.

Comment: @sneha can you put your minimal example and the screenshot of what happens?

Answer (score 1):

I got you, I still don't know why but when you import vpython you kinda already get a scene, in jupyter it seems like it gets stuck where you made your import. But there's another problem.

If you try to create a second simulation or run your current simulation twice, it won't reset the objects already created.

What you should do is to create a canvas on the top of the cell you want the simulation to appear, before running the simulation.

```
canvas()
s = sphere(pos=vector(0,0,0))

for i in range(100):
    rate(100)
    s.pos = s.pos + vector(i/1000,0,0)
```

this should recreate the scene every time you run the cell. I'm not sure how jupyter will handdle memory in this case, but worst case, better having to restart the kernel often than for every test.